# How to count average number of courses taught per staff member? SQL

Tags: sql

I am learning SQL now and I have a DB table COURSE as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE COURSE (COURSE_ID CHAR(6),
 COURSE_TITLE CHAR(20),
 STAFF_ID CHAR(3),
 SECTION NUMBER(2));
```

And another table STAFF:

```
CREATE TABLE STAFF (STAFF_ID CHAR(3),
 STAFF_NAME CHAR(20),
 GENDER CHAR(6),
 DEPARTMENT CHAR(20),
 BOSS_ID CHAR(3)
 SALARY NUMBER(8,2));
```

My Problem is I want to calculate the average number of courses taught per staff member.
I want to have some inspiration and tips on this.

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you essentially **never** want to use the `char` data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT S.STAFF_ID) / (COUNT(C.STAFF_ID) * 1.0) FROM STAFF S LEFT JOIN COURSE C ON S.STAFF_ID = C.STAFF_ID;
```

The first count gives us the number of staff members, the second gives us the number of courses currently being tought by all the staff members. Dividing those two we get the number of courses per staff member.

Answer (score 0):

```
select st.staff_id, st.staff_name, count(crs.course_id)
from staff st inner join course crs on
  st.staff_id = rs.staff_id
group by st.staff_id, st.staff_name;
```

this query will fetch the staff_name,staff_id along with the number of courses that each staff teaches.